# JavaScript library for flowchart editor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowchart

I would like to build a web-based flowchart editor like draw.io. I don't want to use paid APIs. Does anyone know of good free frameworks I could use to build this functionality and UI?

I haven't found any suitable free frameworks.

Comment: I think this is too broad, but you could take a look at https://reactflow.dev/ Its quite customizable so you could maybe build something like drawio with this

Comment: What do you mean by too broad?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Unfortunately, your question is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).